# Android Custom EditText

Tags: android, graphics, view, custom-controls, android-edittext

I am looking to create a custom EditText, where each character entered should lie within its own cell (see image).

My best guess is that I need to create my own .png's for the various states of the EditText, which provide the rectangular outline, then extend EditText's onDraw method to draw the vertical lines that separate adjacent characters.

I've never made a custom view before, and I know little about manual drawing in Android, so some guidance is needed.

Am I on the right path here?

How can I determine how tall and at what location to draw the vertical lines?

What is the best way to eat an oreo?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is gonna be a very difficult task. Just look at [TextView.onDraw()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) (which you are thinking of override). If I were you, I'd immediately change my mind :)

Instead, I'd use a `LinearLayout` to hold an array of customized `EditText`, but I don't know what kind of interaction you are looking for

Finally, to measure text you use [`Paint.getTextBounds()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29). Where to draw vertical separators depends on your design. If you have a fixed number of fixed length cells, you know where, otherwise you need to measure text

Comment: This is really just one of those "nice to have" features, that I'll only really go after if it's simple to do. I will know ahead of time exactly how many characters the EditText has capacity for, and the characters will never extend beyond the visible width of the EditText. Having each cell serve as an EditText will not suffice for many different reasons that I won't bring up. Is there any way to space out the characters such that they are evenly spread horizontally across the width of the EditText?

Comment: None I'm aware of :( maybe using a fixed width font, but I don't know how reliable this method would be